# Adding and removing class with onClick for dynamic button

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have these buttons

```
<button id="btn1" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm margin-left-1">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
</button>

<button id="btn2" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm margin-left-1">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
</button>

...etc
```

And I want to remove the class `glyphicon-chevron-down` and add `glyphicon-chevron-up` after a click on that button.. it's twitter bootstrap collapsing but I want to have a button with an icon there :-)
The id of the record can be put in the button tag or in the span tag, does not matter, is there any way I can check applied CSS?
For example, `${#element}.existCSS?('glyphicon-chevron-down')` ?

Comment: `$("#element").hasClass('glyphicon-chevron-down')`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: thanks DevIshOne thats it.

Comment: @devo: while editing, please don't just add tags - try to fix as much as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$('.btn-default').click(function() { $(this).find('.glyphicon-chevron-down').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up');
});
```

look at this - http://jsfiddle.net/9NDyL/

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if( $(<#element>).hasClass("glyphicon-chevron-down") ) {
 //Your code
}
```

Comment: That is just a placehloder for the element selector in the pseudo code.